# Is there a news feed for Amazon Linux AMI releases?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

This is a pretty mundane question, sorry in advance. I'm just looking for a news feed which *only* contains new Amazon Linux AMI releases. It seems like the [Amazon Web Services Blog](http://aws.typepad.com) feed includes these releases, but it would still be nice to have a dedicated feed for new AMIs.

Comment: Don't apologize. This would be great to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an RSS icon on the [Security Bulletins page](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/security-bulletins/). There are also bots that re-post these entries to [Twitter](https://twitter.com/AmznLinuxSec) and [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/amznlinuxsec) if you prefer.